How to run a query or stored procedure such that its changes can be reverted
I have a very important SQL Server DB on which I want to run some sensitive delete and update queries. I have some stored procedures and some simple queries for it.
I want to run these queries such that if something wrong happens I can just revert the changes done by these queries.
Is there a way this can be achieved?

Backup your database? Inside a transaction that you only commit once you are happy with it else roll back? Take a record of the exact changes made such that they can be exactly reversed. Loads of options... take your pick.

look up transactions

This is tricky. A transaction can be used to allow a rollback but it will likely lock the tables for changes and/or selects until you either commit or rollback. It will allow you to check the data before proceeding though. An alternative is a test database or a snapshot where you test your code before running it in the real one

got it @siggemannen will look into it. Thanks

You misunderstand and of course I write code with errors; all I was suggesting that perhaps you could catch errors earlier in the process.

As per the answers in comment section. There are 2 ways this can be achieved:

Perform operations on a copy test DB.
Use Transactions.

Going with the second way, suppose below are the operations we want to perform (IRL I had some complex SPs but let's consider this for now)
INSERT INTO ValueTable VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO ValueTable VALUES(2);

Then we can start a transaction and execute these changes as below
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO ValueTable VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO ValueTable VALUES(2);
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME;

We can see the logs generated by these operations and decide if we want to proceed or revert by running COMMIT or ROLLBACK respectively as @siggemannen mentioned.

Also, always set SET XACT_ABORT ON before starting transactions so the changes properly disposed on errors
